# How can I calculate pi (π) in VB?

Tags: vb.net, math

Does anyone know how can I calculate pi (π) in VB?

Comment: Voting to close, since "how do I get the value of pi" is so trivial as to be a useless question, and "how do I calculate pi" is not programming related.  The question is sufficiently ambiguous that who knows which one he means.

Comment: Just because the question is trivial to you does not make it trivial to a newcomer to programming.

Comment: Read the SO FAQ. No question is too trivial or beginner.

Comment: It's not that it's trivial. It's the he hasn't tryid to write his own code, and asked for help with specific parts of the code.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
System.Math.Pi
```

Comment: That's not "calculating" it. That's just getting a pre-calculated value.

Answer (score 14):

Assuming you actually want to compute pi instead of just using the built in constants, there are a bunch of ways that you can do it. Here are a few links that could be useful:

- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/CRHpi.aspx
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi#Computation_in_the_computer_age
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machin-like_formula

Comment: Upvoting as this is a more interesting answer.

Answer (score 7):

If you mean VB6, it doesn't have a pi constant. You can use:

```
Dim pi as Double  
pi = 4 * Atn(1)
```

Answer (score 3):

If the OP is asking about algorithms as a learning experience, good for him/her.

If the OP wanted help finding the built-in value, s/he has it now.

But if the goal is a good value of higher precision than the built-in value with a minimum of effort, here's pi to one million digits:

http://www.eveandersson.com/pi/digits/1000000

That should be enough.

I hope the OP isn't asking how to recalculate the value of Pi each and every time it's used.  That would be *madness*.

Answer (score -1):

Meh, so efficient, accurate and most of all boring approximations... Try [this](http://www.modula2.org/projects/pi_by_montecarlo.php) instead! Pseudocode ensues:

- initialize *inside* and *total* as 0
- repeat an insane amount of times:

  - assign both *x* and *y* random values between (and including) 0 and +1.
  - assign *distance* as the square root of (*x*<sup>2</sup> + *y*<sup>2</sup>)
  - if *distance* ≤ 1, add 1 to *inside*
  - add 1 to *total*
- assign *pi* as *inside* / *total* * 4

Answer (score -6):

If you don't want to use the built in values in the .net math library...

22 / 7

Comment: I don't advocate for the use of a fractional approximation vs. the built in value at all, and 22/7 was the first one I could think of off the top of my head :)

Comment: 355/113 is a better approximation :)

Comment: I would rather use a constant float value like 3.14159, rather than 22/7 which is an inaccurate approximation. 22/7 produces the value 3.142857 and it is only useful for elementary school kids. ;-)

Comment: Or someone who doesn't care for any major differences as the data's inaccurate anyway

Comment: 22/7 contains TWO magic numbers whereas 3.14 only contains one! It must be twice as evil!

Comment: 22/7 is only useful for people who missed celebrating Pi day on March 14th, and thus need to celebrate Badly Approximated Pi Day.

Comment: @Artelius: What is magic numbers to you? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(disambiguation)